# "vagrant box add laravel/homestead" results in multiple errors

Tags: laravel, vagrant

[image]

**Setup**

- Windows 8.1
- Latest VirtualBox
- Latest Vagrant

**What I've tried:**

- Reinstallation of Vagrant
- Running Repair on Vagrant
- Rebooting PC
- Restarting CMD prompt

I've tried the installation 4 times, it's very painful as it takes about 45 minutes per box download on my ADSL connection.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered on reddit [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/2dxlwe/vagrant_box_add_laravelhomestead_results_in/cjueofq) but I'll add it here too in case others stumble across this question.

This set of errors will usually be experienced when you run out of disk space on the drive Vagrant uses to store it's boxes and temporary download files. This location defaults to under the users home directory (`C:\Users\Matt\.vagrant.d` in the questions case)

Vagrant lets you specify a number of [environment variables](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/environmental-variables.html) including the location of this `VAGRANT_HOME` directory.

You can change it by running the following in a command prompt:

> REG ADD HKCU\Environment /v VAGRANT_HOME /t REG_SZ /d "E:\Vagrant\vagrant.d"

where `E:\Vagrant\vagrant.d` is the desired location.

Alternatively you can add the environment variable yourself:

- Go to **Control Panel** > **System** > **Advanced System Settings** > **Advanced** > **Environment Variables**
- In the **User variables for *USER*** section click **New...**
- Set the **Variable name** to **VAGRANT_HOME**
- Set the **Variable value** to **E:\Vagrant\vagrant.d**

Changes to environment variables should take effect instantly but you may need to restart cmd.exe instance you are using